# Getting A #DIV/0 Error When Doing "AVERAGEIF"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, ms-word

So, I have a code here that performs AVERAGEIF but I always get a #DIV/0 error. I don't know what seems  to be wrong here. I hope someone  could help.

```
     Dim aveif1
     Dim aveif2
     Dim aveval
     Dim totalave As Variant
     Dim colAve
     Dim aveSource As Range
     Dim aveCheck As Range
     Dim lCol 

     lCol = 19
     colAve = lCol + 1



    For aveif1 = 3 To ColBanner

        aveval = CStr(Cells(1, aveif1).Value)

       For aveif2 = 3 To RowBanner

            With Sheets("Rescaled Scores")

             totalave = Application.AverageIf(Columns(colAve), "Smartphone", Columns(aveif2))

            End With

        colAve = colAve + 1
        Cells(aveif2, aveif1).Value = totalave
        Columns.AutoFit

       Next aveif2



    Next aveif1
```

Comment: Check your data, are there any errors/issues in the data itself?

Comment: I already checked  the data itself ann it has no errors. I would not be asking     here without checking my file first. @BruceWayne

Answer (score 0):

An average is a sum and a division.

What you get is a division by zero error, indicating that one of your data set is empty. In such cases, you cannot perform an average or you will try to divide by zero.